# Override multiple overloaded init() methods in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to create a custom `NSTextFieldCell` subclass in Swift (Xcode Beta 5), with the following code:

```
class CustomHighlightTextFieldCell : NSTextFieldCell {

    required init(coder aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aCoder)
    }

    init(imageCell anImage: NSImage!) {
        super.init(imageCell: anImage)
    }

    init(textCell aString: String!) {
        super.init(textCell: aString)
    }
}
```

However, I receive compilation errors on the 2nd and 3rd `init()` declarations:

```
/Users/Craig/projects/.../CustomHighlightTextFieldCell:8:40: Invalid redeclaration of 'init(imageCell:)'
/Users/Craig/projects/.../CustomHighlightTextFieldCell.swift:17:5: 'init(imageCell:)' previously declared here

/Users/Craig/projects/.../CustomHighlightTextFieldCell:7:39: Invalid redeclaration of 'init(textCell:)'
/Users/Craig/projects/.../CustomHighlightTextFieldCell.swift:21:5: 'init(textCell:)' previously declared here
```

While there are some strange compiler bugs here (I'm getting the usual "SourceKitService Terminated, Editor functionality temporarily limited." message), it seems like I'm missing something in my method overriding - but I can't tell what.

I was under the assumption the named parameters, or at least the parameter *types*, would indicate that there are three different `init()` methods here, but apparently I'm missing a key piece of the puzzle.

**Edit:** If I add `override` to the 2nd and 3rd `init()` methods, I have a separate issue:

```
required init(coder aCoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aCoder)
}

override init(imageCell anImage: NSImage!) {
    super.init(imageCell: anImage)
}

override init(textCell aString: String!) {
    super.init(textCell: aString)
}
```

This new issue (simply invoked by adding the two `override` keywords) seems to almost contradict the original.

```
/Users/Craig/projects/.../CustomHighlightTextFieldCell.swift:17:14: Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass
/Users/Craig/projects/.../CustomHighlightTextFieldCell.swift:21:14: Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem that your declarations (with override) *should* be sufficient, however, they seem to need the @objc declarations as well. This works:

```
class CustomHighlightTextFieldCell : NSTextFieldCell {

    required init(coder aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aCoder)
    }

    @objc(initImageCell:)
    override init(imageCell anImage: NSImage!) {
        super.init(imageCell: anImage)
    }

    @objc(initTextCell:)
    override init(textCell aString: String!) {
        super.init(textCell: aString)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! Sounds like I've got some reading to do regarding `@objc` - this sounds like a bug?

Comment: Well, from reading the Xcode docs it gives the Swift declarations exactly as you had them, without the @objc patterns, so it looks like it might be  a bug.

Comment: I reported that as bug but after one month I even have no feedback. Somewhere I read about more than 1300 bugs with Swift. Admittedly it's better than Obj-C but it still smells. Compared to what this company earns per second this compiler is - well, I should silent down.

Comment: Another great tip who's exact implementation is not found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_86

Answer (score 3):

As you see, you have the corresponding super.init(xxx) in the functions which means you are overriding the functions. So just add the override keyword.

```
override init(imageCell anImage: NSImage!) {
    super.init(imageCell: anImage)
}

override init(textCell aString: String!) {
    super.init(textCell: aString)
}
```

Comment: This is new as of Xcode beta 5 - originally the `override` keyword wasn't required for overridden initializers.

Comment: I tried adding the `override`, I now have a contradicting issue. (Answer updated.)