# Swift: Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

Tags: swift, inheritance, initialization

Im trying to inherit a class I made that inherits NSObject, those are the snippets:

bPlayer.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import QuartzCore

class bluetoothPlayer: player {

    override init (game: MultiGame) {
        super.init(game: game)

    }

}
```

Player.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import QuartzCore

class player: NSObject {

    init (game: NSObject) {
        super.init()

    }

}
```

But I get the following error:

> Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its
>   superclass

If I delete the "override" keyword from the bluetoothPlayer init, the following error comes up instead:

> Initializer 'init(game:)' with Objective-C selector 'initWithGame:'
>   conflicts with initializer 'init(game:)' from superclass 'player' with
>   the same Objective-C selector

Answer (score 2):

That's because you didn't. You didn't *override* the function, you *overloaded* it. You made a new function (`init`) with the same name but *different parameters*. This doesn't count as overriding a function.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047793/function-override-overload-in-java) SO question (in Java, however). See [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255181/override-multiple-overloaded-init-methods-in-swift) SO question about overriding multiple functions in Swift.

This is because `NSObject` ≠ `MultiGame`

You can override your `init` function by declaring it like so in `bluetoothPlayer`:

```
override init (game: NSObject) {
    super.init(game: game)
}
```

You can do a check to make sure that `game` is of type `MultiGame` to achieve the same effect as what you wrote though.